# How can I make this javascript playlist skip missing tracks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, playlist

Let me just start from the beginning. This here below is the script that recognizes the html as a playlist:

```
var audio;
var library;
var tracks;
var current;
init();
function init() {
    current = 0;
    audio = $('.player');
    library = $('.album_tracks_container');
    tracks = library.find('.span-link');
    len = tracks.length;
    var playlist;
    library.find('.span-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        playlist = link.closest('.album_tracks_container');
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e) {
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('.span-link')[0];
        } else {
            link = playlist.find('.span-link')[current];   
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player) {
    player.src = link.attr('data');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play();
}
```

It works great with a html like this one below, and it will play the next track in the list when done playing the current one:

```
<div class="album_container">
    <div class="album_tracks_container">
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album1/01.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album1/02.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album1/03.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album1/04.wav"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It also seem to work fine if I have a html like this, it will skip the third container and start playing the fourth:

```
<div class="album_container">
    <div class="album_tracks_container">
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/01.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/02.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-not-link"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/04.wav"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But say I have a html like this one below, it doesn't seem to work. After playing track 02, it will not switch to track 03:

```
<div class="album_container">
    <div class="album_tracks_container">
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-not-link"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/02.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_light">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/03.wav"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="album_tracks_dark">
            <span class="span-link" data="media/album2/04.wav"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

-edit-

I'm still having troubles figuring this out, but as of previous edit I found out that it has little to do with a missing track, but more to do with whether or not the first track is there or not. If 01.wav is there, the playlist works, but if it isn't, the playlist breaks.

Comment: As i see it, ya, it shouldn't select the element which doesn't have class `span-link`. So can you describe your issue? Is it the exact code you are using? And you should set variable `link` as local, not global

Comment: It is the exact code yes. What happens is that, when done playing it doesn't load the 04.wav and simply stops after playing 02.wav.

Comment: Might it have something to do with current = link.parent().index(); perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it has a file link or not:

```
 playlist.find('.span-link').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).attr("data").length>0){
            e.preventDefault();
            link = $(this);
            current = link.parent().index();
            currentplaylist = link.closest('.album_tracks_container');
            run(link, audio[0]);
       } });
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it doesn't seem to make any difference to the original code. It just moves down to track 03 and stops there (since there's no file to play). It doesn't want to start track 04.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your end listener.

We should check the data link here and if it is not exist, just go to the next one.

Maybe something like this:

```
audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e) {
    current++;
    while(current < len){
        link = playlist.find('.span-link')[current];
        if(!link.attr("data").length) current++;
    }

    if(current == len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('.span-link')[0];
    }

    run($(link),audio[0]);
});
```

Another thing is, if your playlist is not change, it is better to cache
playlist.find('.span-link'), then use it every time.

Have fun. :)

Comment: I tried this with replacing the 'span-not-link' with the regular 'span-link' like the others except with no data attribute. But that made it no longer want to play next song in even complete playlists. I made another discovery too, it is in the OP now.